# Why the vertical height of the liquid column remains same after tilting the tube in the Barometer here?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics

[image: Simple Barometer]

In this case, if we slant the tube, then more mercury is present in the tube which would cause more pressure at the bottom, but the height of mercury remains the same which according to Pascal's law dives the same pressure = rhoxgxh. I could relate this case to one of those cases of Hydrostatic Paradoxes, but I could not understand how the principle of hydrostatic paradox applies here.

Comment: Why does slanting the tube increase the volume of mercury in the tube? how did you prove that?

Comment: what would be the height of the mercury if the tube was two meters in diameter?

Answer (score 2):

it's measured in the height of mercury, not the length of mercury.